# TempData not showing in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tempdata

Working on a MVC4 project, I've got a View that lists some records. It has a specific `div` to show messages that is hidden by default, because `TempData["Feedback"]` is empty:

```
<a href="../MasterData/DeleteConcession">Delete</a>
...
@if (TempData["Feedback"] != null)
{
    <div class="success-centered">
        @TempData["Feedback"]
    </div>
}
```

In a controller, I have a method to delete a record.

```
...
    if (rt.totalErrors == "0")
    {
        TempData["Feedback"] = "Record deleted";
    }
    else
    {
        TempData["Feedback"] = rt.resultDescription;
    }
}
return Redirect("../MasterData/Index");
```

The record is actually deleted and the datagrid is refreshed (already without the deleted record) but the `div` that contains the `TempData` doesn't show.

**Note:** If the user refreshes the page, then it shows.

Why isn't the `TempData` displayed after the record deletion?

### EDIT

1. Note that the link is in a partial view: is this relevant for this issue?
2. Is there an alternative (in this case) to show a feedback message other than in a `div`? Maybe a popup window or something? I'm considering some other approach since it seems to be so odd and others seem to agree that it's very odd.
3. Also, just to illustrate better what is happening:

   - There is a datagrid, I select an item and press the link `Delete`;
     it deletes the record and refreshes the datagrid. The `Tempdata`
     isn't showing. If I refresh the page, the `TempData` shows! If I
     refresh again, it disappears.
   - So, the `TempData` should be displayed after the deletion and disappear if the page was refreshed afterwards.

Comment: Just for clarity, although I think that it only changed between MVC 1 > 2, Which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I'm using MVC4: I'll add this information to the question

Comment: Also is TempData["Feedback"] null? It seems whether there are errors or not you are setting it to something (that is not null). Then when they refresh the page you say (so tempdata is reset then) you do see it. Do you see the problem?\

Comment: No, it is not null. It's null the very first time the user sees the listing page but gets filled when the user deletes a record, for example. Then, despite having a value, the `div` that contains it doesn't show (it should) and if the user refreshes the page, it shows.

Comment: So you placed a breakpoint in your view and saw there was data and it still ignored your if?

Comment: Yes @MikeCheel, that is the case. You can see it in the code I put in the question that `TempData` is populated

Comment: I setup a similar test on my box here and it works (using mvc 5 though but shouldn't make a difference). Something else is (obviously) going on. Is your second code redirecting to itself then (just to be sure)? I'm confused as to which file is which above.

Comment: The delete method and `..MasterData/Index` are in the same controller. It's redirecting to the Index method within the same controller.

Comment: Are you sure your page isn't simply showing cached content?  And thus not actually rendering the action?  The fact it shows on refresh leads me to believe this is the case.  BTW, you should probably use RedirectToAction() rather than Redirect.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch, maybe that's the case, I don't know. I suppose it may be showing cached content. However, it has a grid in it that is refreshed, unlike the rest. I just to make it show the view fully refreshed

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have done everything right, just to verify set a break point in the view

```
@if (TempData["Feedback"] != null)
{
<div class="success-centered">
    @TempData["Feedback"]
 </div>
```

whether @TempData["Feedback"] contains a value or not.

In this scenario you can check with viewData[""].

It will surely help.

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan. Thanks for your effort. Although it should be in form of a comment and not an answer (because it's not one). It may be downvoted for that reason